# Inheritance with wp_enqueue_scripts()

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to build a plugin in wordpress, and I've encountered this issue where I need to include a .js from another plugin into my own. I tried it using `wp_enqueue_script()` by adding the other .js as a dependency for my .js, but to no avail.

> ```
> wp_enqueue_script('parent-script', '/parent-script.js', array('jquery'), false);
> wp_enqueue_script('child-script', '/child-script.js', array('jquery', 'parent-script'), false);
> ```

I need to call a variable from the parent-script and use it in the child-script. Is it possible? If so, how do I proceed with it?

Edit : Removed the parent-script dependency from the parent-script enqueue, following the comment of Chris.

Also, to be more specific, suppose parent-script is this :

```
jQuery(function($){
    var foo = "This is from parent script";
});
```

Will using `wp_enqueue_script()` like I have above let me use `foo` from the child script? If not, is there any way for me to access it from the child script?

Comment: The parent script _must not_ list itself as a dependency of itself, only the child script should do this.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thank you for your input! I've updated the post accordingly, but my question still remains. I've made it more specific. Please check it and let me know if there's anything that can be done and thanks again :)

Comment: That variable will be scoped to that function, that’s just the nature of JavaScript. One option is to put it in the global scope by doing `window.foo = "xyz";`. If you do this, I’d make sure that `foo` is ver unique, so `window.myAppFoo`. Is this var really made in JS or in PHP? If the latter, that’s actually what [`wp_localize_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) is for

Comment: The variable is made in JS. I'm guessing due to the scope of it, the only way to do what I need is by making the variable global. Thanks, it should work for me for now. We should however avoid making global variables as best as we can, right?

Comment: Yes, the general guidance in most programming languages is to avoid global scope whenever possible, however most/all systems still use it to some degree. In JS, a common pattern is to create an _object_ in global scope that has a name unique to you, and set your properties on that. Another option that is a little more complicated is to use events. Maybe your first plugin fires the “Data has been set” event that your second plugin listens for